# Running a macro from a specific sheet in the same workbook

Tags: vba, excel

The macro that follows works alright if I put it in sheet1. However I would like to put this macro in sheet2. Unfortunately it doesn't make the job from sheet2, only from Sheet1. Can you please help me to make it run from Sheet2?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng As Range
Dim sRes As Variant
On Error GoTo haveError

Set rng = Application.Intersect(Sheet1.Range("I15:I18"), Target)


If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    If rng.Cells.count = 1 Then
        sRes = Application.VLookup(rng.Value, _
               Sheet2.Range("A56:B58"), 2, True)
        'turn off events before updating the worksheet
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = IIf(IsError(sRes), "???", sRes)
        Select Case rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Case "Low Risk": rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = Date + 180

            Case "Medium Risk": rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = Date + 150

            Case "High Risk": rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = Date + 120

        End Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If '<< edit added missing line here
End If
Exit Sub

haveError:
Application.EnableEvents = True '<< ensures events are reset
End Sub
```

Comment: how about changing `sheet1` in the code into `sheet2`

Comment: Just remove `Sheet1.` in `Application.Intersect(Sheet1.Range("I15:I18"), Target)`

Comment: Why dont you put the code in a module (instead of sheet) and change all sheet reference (sheet1, sheet2 etc.) to Activesheet?

Comment: The last suggestion works in part as it runs part of the macro as module. It doesn't put the offset values in

Comment: @ArindamD because this has to be in a worksheet because it is a `Worksheet_Change` event? Therefore you can not put this sub into a module. Also it is a bad practice to use `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: Hi Peh, do you have any suggestion in this regard: @ArindamD because this has to be in a worksheet because it is a Worksheet_Change event? Therefore you can not put this sub into a module. Also it is a bad practice to use ActiveSheet. Can you please tell me how to sort it out my primary question? Many thanks

Comment: @tom No I can't because of lack of information. (1) You didn't tell us what your code actually does and what you expect it to do. (2) Nor did you tell us what is exactly going wrong ("*doesn't make the job*" is a totally useless error description). (3) Nor do we know how your sheets 1 and 2 look like. To get a useful answer [edit] your question (not in a comment) and add the missing information and/or include a [mcve] to reproduce your issue. Also have a look at [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Comment: Thanks Peh, I will try my best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question it is simpler than I thought:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng1 As Range

Dim sRes As Variant
Dim sRes1 As Variant
On Error GoTo haveError

Set rng = Application.Intersect(Sheet1.Range("I15:I18"), Target)
Set rng1 = Application.Intersect(Sheet1.Range("I20:I23"), Target)
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    If rng.Cells.count = 1 Then
        sRes = Application.VLookup(rng.Value, _
               Sheet2.Range("A56:B58"), 2, True) 'Waterlow
        'turn off events before updating the worksheet
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = IIf(IsError(sRes), "???", sRes)
        Select Case rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Case "Low Risk": rng.Offset(0, 2).Value =  Date + 180
            Case "Medium Risk": rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = Date + 150      
            Case "High Risk": rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = Date + 120

        End Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If '<< edit added missing line here

ElseIf Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
If rng1.Cells.count = 1 Then
        sRes1 = Application.VLookup(rng1.Value, _
               Sheet3.Range("A28:B30"), 2, True) 'MUST
        'turn off events before updating the worksheet
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        rng1.Offset(0, 1).Value = IIf(IsError(sRes1), "???", sRes1)
        Select Case rng1.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Case "Low Risk": rng1.Offset(0, 2).Value = Date + 180
            Case "Medium Risk": rng1.Offset(0, 2).Value = Date + 150
            Case "High Risk": rng1.Offset(0, 2).Value = Date + 120

        End Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If '<< edit added missing line here
   End If
Exit Sub

haveError:
Application.EnableEvents = True '<< ensures events are reset
End Sub
```

It is only a matter to combine two procedures. A simple Elseif make it run (work :)) the macro. 
Thanks to all of you for trying to help me.